# a problem when i use cross-entropy loss as a loss function

Tags: pytorch

when i using cross-entropy loss as a loss function, i get this Dimension out of range error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\testcode\cnn.py", line 122, in <module>
    loss = loss_func(output, b_y)   # cross entropy loss
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 916, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2021, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1317, in log_softmax
    ret = input.log_softmax(dim)
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

and the loss function is

```
loss = loss_func(output, b_y)
```

the value of output is

```
tensor([-0.3507,  0.2214,  0.3781,  0.3057], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

the value of b_y is

```
tensor([3])
```

Comment: shouldn't output and b_y have same shape?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to the `CrossEntropyLoss` has to be a 2d tensor with the shape of `[batch size x number of classes]`. If you are only calculating the loss for a single batch, `unsqueeze` the logits before passing them to the loss function.

```py
logits = torch.tensor([-0.3507,  0.2214,  0.3781,  0.3057]).unsqueeze(0)
targets = torch.tensor([3])
loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

loss_func(logits, targets)
```